# Is it possible to change CIDR network flannel and Kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cidr, kubeadm

Is it possible to change CIDR network flannel on running Kubernetes cluster?
If yes what will happen with  the launched pods?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to change [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) CIDR network pool in the following way:

Assuming that you have installed a fresh k8s cluster via [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) builder tool with adopting appropriate `--pod-network-cidr` flag in `kubeadm init` command:

Override `podCIDR` parameter on the particular k8s [Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/) resource with a new IP source range, desirable way with piping output:

```
$ kubectl get no $hostname -o yaml >> file.yaml | sed -i "s~$old_ip~$new_ip~" file.yaml| kubectl delete no $hostname && kubectl create -f file.yaml
```

Replace "Network" field under `net-conf.json` header in the relevant Flannel [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) with a new network IP range:

```
$ kubectl edit cm kube-flannel-cfg -n kube-system
```

> net-conf.json: |
>       {
>         "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
>         "Backend": {
>           "Type": "vxlan"
>         }
>       }

Wipe current CNI network interfaces remaining the old network pool:

```
$ sudo ip link del cni0; sudo ip link del flannel.1
```

Re-spawn Flannel and CoreDNS pods respectively:

```
$ kubectl delete pod --selector=app=flannel -n kube-system
$ kubectl delete pod --selector=k8s-app=kube-dns -n kube-system
```

Wait until CoreDNS pods obtain IP address from a new network pool. Keep in mind that your custom Pods will still retain the old IP addresses inside containers unless you re-create them manually as well.

Comment: Why is it so involved? I just went and used kubeadm reset and started building the cluster from scratch with another setting for --pod-network-cidr. It would make sense if kubeadm would provide simple cli support to change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

For calico, create new IPpool and and disable old.... https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/networking/migrate-pools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/509176)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).